# how to use std::enable_if correctly in this case

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I have the following method defined:

```
template <typename Interface>
Interface Create();
```

with this implementation:

```
template <typename Interface>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<Interface>::value, Interface>::type Create()
{
...
}
```

but now I get the following errors: "undefined reference to ITestInterface* Create()"

when I remove the `std::enable_if`, everything works fine. But I require it to work since I want to add versions of this function that work when Interface is a reference or when Interface is a `std::vector`. What am I doing wrong here? I also noticed that this is a linker error - but I don't know why. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: It sounds like there's another function `Create` involved, that is declared but not defined. When SFINAE fails, this other function could be chosen by overload resolution, which then produces the linker error.

Comment: the question is, why does SFINAE fail - is_pointer should be true in this case. And yes, there is no other implementation so if it fails it should not link according to what you said.

Comment: Wait -- the first code block is intended to be the forward-declaration / function prototype of the second code block?

Comment: yes, it is. What's wrong?

Comment: In that case, just remove the SFINAE temporarily, and add a `static_assert`. Then you should be able to see the type of the template argument.

Comment: It's not the same function template. The return type is part of the signature of a function template. Consider `template<class T> typename std::enable_if< std::is_pointer<T>::value, int* > func(); template<class T> typename std::enable_if< not std::is_pointer<T>::value, void > func();`

Comment: Properly declared, [it works correctly](http://ideone.com/XQOfaT).

Comment: so basically I have to declare each variant of it separately? And the function in this example is basically gone when Interface does not have pointer type?

Comment: What do you mean by each variant?

Comment: @TobiasLangner The second function template does not produce a function for the overload set when the template argument is not a pointer type, yes. Other functions may still contribute to the overload set. (For example, unqualified name lookup is still affected by the existence of this function template, even if it cannot be instantiated for these arguments.)

Comment: @AlanStokes: by variant I mean a function with the same signature except that it has `typename std::enable_if<std::is_reference<Interface>::value, Interface>::type` as return type for example

Comment: Yes you need to declare all these variants individually. You might want to consider using tag dispatch instead.

Comment: Then yes, each one needs to have a separate declaration - they are different templates.

Comment: you could also do something hideous, [such as this](http://ideone.com/gQJzOD).

Comment: Thank you all - dyp, WhozCraig - could someone please post this as answer as well? Then I'd upvote / accept.

Comment: Not sure what you want posted as an answer, the full decl, the hideous aftermath, or just a redeux of the comments in this chain. I'll leave it to dyp though. he did a lot of the legwork on this.

Comment: one question - does this work independet of `Create` being a member function of a class or not?

Answer (score 3):

Whereas in normal function, *return type* doesn't be part of signature,
*return type* does be part of signature for template function.
So

```
template <typename Interface> Interface Create();
```

differs than

```
template <typename Interface>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<Interface>::value, Interface>::type
Create();
```

You have to use same signature in declaration and definition.

As partial specialization is not possible on function, you have to use helper class:
Something like may help:

```
namespace detail
{

template <typename > struct CreateHelper;

template <typename T> struct CreateHelper<T*>
{
    static T* create() {
        // Implementation with T*
    }
};

template <typename T> struct CreateHelper<T&>
{
    static T& create() {
        // Implementation with T&
    }
};

template <typename T> struct CreateHelper<std::vector<T>>
{
    static std::vector<T> create() {
        // Implementation with std::vector<T>
    }
};

} // namespace detail


template <typename Interface> Interface Create()
{
    return detail::CreateHelper<Interface>::create();
}
```

Comment: actually, it's possible without helper classes - at least on gcc/mingw where I tried. Due to enable_if, only one of my 3 implementations appear in the overload resolution and everything is fine.